# Converting exc file to php file?

Tags: php, xml, excel, type-conversion

I am making some multilang site and want to work with excel file that is look like this

[image]

This i want convert to php file like this

```
$text1='What do "you" think';
$text2='About';
$text3='Home';
$text4='Contact';
```

Is it possible to make it wortk like that on upload convert that exce file to .php file?

Comment: Nice comment, any point that i can look for?

Comment: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could first export it to a .txt file, check this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx#BMexport

Then do some coding to formatting them, good luck. ;-)